# Difference between 'measured with' and 'measured using'

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference

This may be a silly question. In the sentence 'X was measured **with** a galvanometer', does the use of the word 'with' instead of 'using' convey the meaning that X was measured *along with* a galvanometer?

Which of course does not make sense, but to be correct should we not say 'X was measured **using** a galvanometer'? Or am I wrong and both usages are acceptable in this context? The use of 'with' instead of 'using is very common, [as you can see](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=%22measured%20with%20a%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&gfe_rd=cr&ei=Db8iWfS4PIqDvATk1rPQBA&gws_rd=ssl). Which is why I feel this might be a silly question and that I might be nitpicking.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*With* has more than one meaning. [Sense 7 in Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/with#Preposition):

> Using as an instrument; by means of.
>
> > cut **with** a knife